# VB.net Retrieving dataset values from a particular column into a string

Tags: vb.net

I need to copy structure of selected database to a new database. How is it possible? I am not able to retrieve the `DataSet` value. I need to use this value to retrieve the table names associated with the database. Here is my code.

```
cmd.CommandText = "create database " & txtCustId.Text & "AAA"
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Dim dtadapt As New SqlDataAdapter("select table_name from " & name & ".INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'", comm_con)
Dim dtset As New DataSet
dtadapt.Fill(dtset)
Dim dttb As DataTable = dtset.Tables(0)
'Dim row As Integer = 1
Dim arrS As String = ""
while dttb.Rows.Count > 0 
    'arrS =Convert.ToString(dtset.Tables[i].Rows[0]["table_name"])
    arrS = dttb("table_name").ToString
    cmd.CommandText = " SELECT * INTO " & txtCustId.Text & "AAA.dbo." & arrS & " FROM " & name & ".dbo." & arrS & " where 1=1"

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    'MessageBox.Show("done")
End while
```

Comment: This has some scary sql injection implications. How is user input filtered for malicious data? I know the normal query parameter technique won't be an option there, but you should still have something to prevent sql injection.

Comment: Also: SELECT INTO doesn't get everything. It misses things like indexes, constraints, triggers, keys... This may be okay for what you're doing, but it's something to be aware of.